# Is there an efficient way to detect if a string contains a substring which is in a large set of characteristic strings?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, contains

For example, given a string `aaaaaaaaaXyz`, I want to find out if it contains a substring which is in a characteristic string set `{'xy','xyz','zzz','cccc','dddd',....}`, which may have one million members. Is there an efficient way?

Comment: Maybe the Aho-Corasick algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) can help?

Comment: Depends on many cases, if you are querying much time then pre-processing can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hint of [Clashsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4138801/clashsoft),I found [the java implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115624/aho-corasick-for-multiple-exact-string-matching-in-java) of Aho-Corasick algorithm , which is the one i want ,thanks for Clashsoft

Answer (score 2):

Given that your search set might be very large, I would recommend just iterating that set and checking for a potential substring match:

```
public boolean containsSubstring(String input, Set<String> subs) {
    boolean match = false;

    for (String sub : subs) {
        if (input.contains(sub)) {
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return match;
}
```

Comment: This is not an "efficient" way.

Comment: @Olivier how is it not efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you prepare the `dictionary`. just like this

```
Set<String> stringSet = Set.of("xy", "xyz", "zzz", "zzy", "cccc", "dddd");
Map<Character, List<String>> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
for (String word : stringSet)
    dictionary.computeIfAbsent(word.charAt(0), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(word);
System.out.println(dictionary);
```

output:

```
{c=[cccc], d=[dddd], x=[xyz, xy], z=[zzy, zzz]}
```

And you can use this method to find out.

```
static boolean contains(String input, Map<Character, List<String>> dictionary) {
    for (int i = 0, max = input.length(); i < max; ++i) {
        char first = input.charAt(i);
        if (dictionary.containsKey(first))
            for (String word : dictionary.get(first))
                if (input.startsWith(word, i))
                    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```